# Finding an exception for a seemingly universal form of functionals

Tags: functional-analysis

How to prove that not every $f\in l_\infty^*$ functional is in the form of $f=f_y$, where $ y=(y_n)\in l_1 $ and $$ f_y(x)=\sum_n x_ny_n, \, x=(x_n)\in l_\infty$$?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Hahn-Banach extension theorem on the subspace of sequences $f \in l_\infty$ for which $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n$ exists.